# Can red-black tree be used for best-fit algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, tree, allocator

I know that the best-fit algorithm has to search through the whole list in order to find the best memory block which takes O(n), so I'm thinking about using a red-black tree to improve the runtime to O(logN). Will there be any cases that the red-black tree won't work for best-fit? If so, could someone provide me an example ? Thank you.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit about "best-fit"? I'm not sure what you mean. An example would be enough.

Comment: Let's suppose input is a list of number another number x = 3. If the list has 3, we output 3, if not, we must output the smallest number that is greater than 3.
Ex: Input {4,6,8,3,1,2}, x = 3 => output 3
      Input {4,6,8,3,1,2}, x = 5 => output 6

Answer (score 1):

A red-black tree works fine, but it's not a really good choice.

Since it takes O(size) time to make good use of O(size) bytes, it's better to use a finger search tree of some kind that makes finding small blocks faster at the expense of taking more time to find large blocks: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_search_tree

Also, you probably just want to have separate free lists for some of the smallest possible sizes.  You can expect to hit several cache lines when you search in and update a search tree.  Each cache line is 64 bytes on x86, so just one cache line is enough to store the head pointers for 8 free lists.  If you put the head pointers for free lists for the 8 smallest sizes in one cache line, then allocating blocks of those sizes will be much faster.

This also lets you allocate blocks that are smaller than a red-black tree node.

Answer (score 0):

If you are to build a red-black tree to do what you are describing, there are better options.

Given `n` elements, the red-black tree construction time takes O(n log n). It's the same time from just sorting the array and using binary search, which is way simpler and very performant.

Obviously the tree would be better if elements were constantly added to the array.